# Android creating internal gps points

Tags: java, android, gps, coordinates

I would like to be able to label specific internal points on a gps from a specific building. For example: Using a blueprint from your house, we label each room in the home with a specific gps point, like: "my room", "living room", "bathroom", etc. I'm not sure exactly how to approach this issue.

Comment: First of all, GPS isn't going to be precise enough to tell apart a bathroom and the bedroom next to it, even if no walls were causing multipath and fade interference in the signal. With the interference I'd expect even poorer precision and accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Which still leaves me a bit clueless on how to create an algorithm for this problem. It was the only thing I could really relate this problem to.